# How to restore default fonts on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, font, file

I have deleted the Lucida Grande font from my system, and system bars and menus are full of weird characters. I cannot use my MBA properly. How can I restore system fonts without losing my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place [LucidaGrande.ttc](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/a5yr5bb87pajdf6/LucidaGrande.ttc) in /System/Library/Fonts/.

You can extract fonts from your OS X install media using [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) or grab a copy from your backup or another Mac with similar build/version.

For more information regarding recovering system files, see:

- [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac)

Answer (score 5):

You can also copy the font from the recovery partition:

`diskutil mount Recovery\ HD;hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg;sudo cp /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Library/Fonts/Base/LucidaGrande.ttc /System/Library/Fonts`

Comment: good option if one does not have the install media!

Comment: should one run `diskutil unmount Recovery\ HD` or something afterward?

Comment: Yeah, you can unmount the volume with `diskutil unmount Recovery\ HD` but it doesn't matter if you leave it mounted.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `sudo fontrestore default`.

From the man page:

> ```
> NAME
>      fontrestore -- Restore the available system fonts to a pristine state, if
>      possible.
>
> SYNOPSIS
>      fontrestore default [-n]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>      fontrestore detects fonts in /Library/Fonts, /System/Library/Fonts, and
>      ~/Library/Fonts which are not part of the system install and moves them
>      to /Library/Fonts (Removed), /System/Library/Fonts (Removed), and
>      ~/Library/Fonts/Fonts (Removed) directories. Critical fonts required for
>      operation of the user interface are also restored.
>
>      The [-n] option performs the same operation without touching the disk,
>      describing what would be done without actually doing it.
> ```