# Fix broken system font

Tags: macos, font, dialog, font-book

I manually transferred some of the fonts from my old Mac via Fontbook to my retina MacBook Pro. After doing this the font for system popups broke. How can I fix it?

Here is an example:
[image: broken system font dialog]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore default fonts on Mavericks?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113107/how-to-restore-default-fonts-on-mavericks) — the link in my answer is the retina-optimised font for the rMBP.

Comment: Try a safe boot to clear the font caches http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14204

Comment: I'm not sure if LucidiaGrande.ttc is the font I'm missing. I tried the second terminal command, but it didn't seem to work. Perhaps it would require a restart?

Comment: Maybe it does, can you restart to see whether this is the case?

Comment: You should certainly restart, and do the safe boot if you have not done so already.  It's unlikely you are missing Lucida Grande, the OS has just lost its location temporarily and instead is showing the Last Resort font.